# Edit legend Tilemill legend items

Tags: web-mapping, tilemill, mapbox

[image]

I am trying to edit my legend in tilemill to add a "Note". What I did was essentially copy the   legend-source code to do this. However, I would like the line spacing in the "Note" section to be smaller. I have looked at the CartoCSS manual but am sitll not quite getting what I should do.

Here is my legend code. What code should I write to make the line spacing in the "Notes" paragraph smaller?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line to your '.legend-source' like this:

```
line-height: 1;
```

Or whatever. To find this out, just google for html line size or something like that.